# Python dns timeout while running in Celery but not while running in Interactive shell

Tags: python, dns, celery

There is something which is funny, I have the following external function.

```
def get_A_records(domain, default="A"):
    """
    Get the A Records of a domain
    """
    try:
        resolver  = Resolver()
        a_record = resolver.query(domain, default)
        a_records = list()
        
        for r in a_record:
            a_dict = dict()

            a_dict["domain"]=domain
            a_dict["a_ip"]=r.address
            a_dict["rtype"]=default
            a_records.append(a_dict)
            
        return a_records
            
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return {}
```

When I import this function and i run it in the interactive shell, it was in less than a second

The function is meant to be used in celery. But when I invoke the function in celery

```
@app.task
def update_domain(domain):
    try:
       ips_v4 = get_A_records(domain)
    except Exception as e:
       print("Failure... recorded!")
```

I get the following error

Why is it like that? And What is an alternative? Thanks!

Comment: Please don't post pictures of error messages. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution a working one. In case someone faces the same problem.

Use asynchronous dns module which is supported in dnspython.

```
from dns import asyncresolver
import dns

async def async_get_A_records(domain, default):
        """
        Asyncrhonous
        """
        a_record = await asyncresolver.resolve(domain, default)
        a_records = list()

        for r in a_record:

            a_dict = dict()

            a_dict["domain"]=domain
            a_dict["a_ip"]=r.address
            a_dict["rtype"]=default
            a_records.append(a_dict)
    
       return a_records
```

Now in celery app.task

```
async def query_domain_a(domain):
    result = await async_get_A_records(domain)
    print(result)

@app.task
def update_domain(domain):
    try:
       asyncio.run(query_domain_a(domain, "A"))
       asyncio.run(query_domain_a(domain, "AAAA"))
    except Domain.DoesNotExist as E:
        print(E)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

And you won't see timeouts.
HEADS-UP. It is really discouraged by the celery docs to use asyncio or run none asynchronous task.